# python strptime() parsing, use now parameter by default

Tags: python, strptime

I want to parse such "14 day 16 h" by using `datetime.datetime.strptime()` method, `strptime('14 day 16 h', '%d day %H h')`, but it give me a `datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 14, 16, 0)`, how to make other time parameter use now by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can replace the default datetime values (alright, I'm sure you must be able to somewhere, but I'm not sure how) but you could use [datetime.replace](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) to get your desired results:

```
import datetime 
time = datetime.datetime.strptime('14 day 16 h', '%d day %H h')
currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
time = time.replace(year=currentTime.year, month=currentTime.month)
```

Similarly you could edit any other "default" datetime value you would like to.

Answer (score 1):

```
strptime('14 day 16 h','%d day %H h')
```

please the order of the argument

Comment: thanks, but output is `datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 14, 16, 0)` ,  not today